# Firebase Firestore rules for shared content

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm developing a simple app that can upload photos. I'm using firebase firestore and storage. Every time I upload a new photo I create an object like this:

```
struct Item: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID // photo name
    var uidOwner: String // uid user owner
    var emailOwner: String // email user owner
    var path: String // photo path
    var shared: [String] = []
}
```

For now I'm just using this rules for checks that the user email is it contained in the "shared" data of every document.

```
enter rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /photos/{photo} {
    allow read if: resource.data.emailOwner in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/photos/$(photo)).data.shared;
}}}
```

In Swift project I take this query:

```
enter func getItems() async throws -> [Item] {
    do {
        let querySnapshot = try await photoCollection
            .whereField("emailOwner", arrayContains: user.email ?? "test@gmail.com")
            .getDocuments()
        let items = try querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { doc in
            return try doc.data(as: Item.self)
        }
        return items
    } catch {
        throw error
    }
}
```

I'm logging in with an email contained within the shared array in a document. Why doesn't that use have access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recognize that ["Security Rules are not filters"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).  The security rules do not look at the documents being returned by a request to determine the validity of the request.  They look at the REQUEST itself to determine if the REQUEST is valid or not.

Your rule (if using Puf's answer) says:

```
allow read if: resource.data.emailOwner in resource.data.shared;
```

but your query is:

```
.whereField("emailOwner", arrayContains: user.email ?? "test@gmail.com")
```

So your query is says "if the array `emailOwner` contains the following value (`user.email ?? test@gmail.com`)"

Your query is looking at `in emailOwner` but your rule is looking at `in shared`.

Answer (score 0):

If I read it correctly, you don't get `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/photos/$(photo))` at all, as you're just loading the document under consideration - and that probably is why a `list`/`getDocuments` calls fails: there's no way for Firestore to consider all the possible documents.

But since you're just using the document under consideration, you can use:

```
allow read if: resource.data.emailOwner in resource.data.shared;
```

The rules engine might be able to evaluate this statically, which would allow a `list`/`getDocuments` call to work.

Comment: Hello, I try this rules but it didn't work.. but I can't understand why..
I have to read the documents by taking only those that in the shared field contain the email address of the logged in user... nothing seems to work. (The error is: [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Listen for query at photos failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.)